# c++: Undefined reference to ERROR

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, cpd

I want to add new c++ library of cpd (https://github.com/gadomski/cpd) to one project in ROS.
I have already successfully installed the cpd library in my Ubuntu OS.

Now I want to use it under ROS environment.

In the CMakeList.txt file, I already added the line of

```
find_package(CPD REQUIRED)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${CPD_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(background_removal
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
  ${CPD_LIBRARIES}
)
```

then in the source code I just added

```
#include <cpd/nonrigid_lowrank.hpp>
```

as well as the example code

```
cpd::NonrigidLowrank reg;
cpd::Registration::ResultPtr result = reg.run(X, Y);
```

But after I compile it, it throws the error: undefined reference to `cpd::NonrigidLowrank::NonrigidLowrank()'

error: undefined reference to `cpd::Registration::run(arma::Mat const&, arma::Mat const&) const'

I suppose the library of cpd is not linked to the ROS, Did I do something wrong to call the cpd library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined reference` is a linker error, not a compiler error. Your use of `include_directories()` is OK, but you forgot to also add `${CPD_LIBRARIES}` (1)(2) to the `target_link_libraries()` of your target(s).

---

(1): Just guessing that FindCPD.cmake "works" the same way as all the other FindXyz.cmake modules. Never worked with CPD myself.

(2): Guessing from your snippet, you will also need to add `${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}` and `${PCL_LIBRARIES}`...

Comment: hey, thx for your reply. I did add the target_link_libraries in my CMakeList file

    target_link_libraries(background_removal
      ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
      ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
      ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
      ${CPD_LIBRARIES}
   )

But it didn't work, Without use of CPD, I can successfully run it with OpenCV, PCL.

Comment: Well, the usual stuff: `message( "CPD_LIBARIES: ${CPD_LIBRARIES}" )`, `grep` for the reported-missing symbols in those libraries... not enough information here to give more precise advice.

Comment: you are right, there is no value in the symbol, it's empty. so it does not actually find the cpd libary...

Comment: i manually set target_link_libraries(background_removal 
/usr/local/lib/libcpd.so) to the pcd lib, it works, but still don't get why it does not work with find_package, but your reply helped a lot

Comment: @ZYJ: There's half a dozen possible reasons. Headers installed but not the libs? Looking for debug libs but only finding release (or vice versa)? Looking for static libs but only having dynamic ones (or vice versa)? Working on Cygwin (where libs get prefxied cyg...) and find module not being prepared for it? Headers in a standard location but libs not (would require `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` being set appropriately)? You can debug all this by scattering some `message(...)` entries throughout the find module and checking where it goes wrong.